# CSS3 re-size page according to screen size / display

Tags: html, css

how can i get my page to align to fit into any any screen size, for example, take a look at this link for a better understanding https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8542058/Photo%20Jul%2012%2C%209%2056%2026.png
if you notice, on the link above, once the screen is adjusted, the image on the screen adjust it self and take the shape of the screen accordingly. now i want to do the same to my page, my demo page can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/529Lk/show/, and the codes are http://jsfiddle.net/529Lk/. thanks

for easy view my codes are still here:

CSS3:

```
body{
font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
color:#000;
background:#088A08;
font-weight: bold;
margin:auto;           
}
/* SLIDE Start */

input[id=slideThree] {
visibility: hidden;
}

/* SLIDE THREE */
.slideThree {
width: 120px;
height: 45px;
background: #0101DF;

-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
position: relative;

-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    position:relative; left:450px;
}

.slideThree:after {
content: 'OFF';
font: 19px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
z-index: 0;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}

 .slideThree:before {
content: 'ON';
font: 19px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
z-index: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}

.slideThree label {
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 40px;

-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;

-webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease;
-o-transition: all .4s ease;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease;
transition: all .10s ease;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
left: 3px;
z-index: 1;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background: #fcfff4;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4',   endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
left: 68px;
}

.back { width:598; height:95px;  background:url('http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/btn_push01c2x.png') no-repeat;      }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="back" id="toggle"><br/>
<label for="enjoy_web"></label>
<div class="slideThree">
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" />
<label for="slideThree"></label>
</div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<img src="http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/btn_push01a2x.png"/>​
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean If I were to shrink the browser, it would still fit? That is what you would call a fluid-width style. This can be done by using percentages on widths.

On the other hand, if you want to apply separate styles to your page depending on the screen resolution, then you can use media queries: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries